# Not able to create zip folder in play framework

Tags: java, regex, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have developed the code in Scala 2.11 using play framework 2.2.2 and trying to create the zip folder to deploy the code. I am using following command:

play ~dist

But I am getting below error:

```
[error] (*:rjsPaths) java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 47
[error] ['"]?([^\s'"]*)['"]?\s*:\s*[\[]?.*['"].*/lib\(.*)['"]
[error]                                                ^
```

Comment: It looks like the escaped opening round bracket in `\(.*)` produces this issue. Can you remove the ``\``?

Answer (score 0):

Ya, Why you escape the last opening parenthesis?

```
['"]?([^\s'"]*)['"]?\s*:\s*[\[]?.*['"].*/lib(.*)['"]
                                            ^
```

If you do escape the  opening parenthesis then the regex engine would got confused on treating a `)` closing parenthesis without a  group haven't opened.